# dequeueReusableCell method return new or reusable object?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Unable to understand UITableview call to "dequeueReusableCell" method. How does the dequeue process happen in UITableview? 
Are we getting reusable cell or always getting new one?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a very simple mechanism. There are just two cases when you ask `tableView` (or `collectionView`) for a reusable cell by calling `dequeueReusableCell`:

1. There is no reusable cell in the queue that could be returned (all existing cells are visible and thus cannot be reused) - the `tableView` has to create a new cell by calling `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)` and it returns this new cell instance.
2. Some of the previously visible cells registered by the same `reuseIdentifier` has gone off the screen before, and now is waiting in the queue. `tableView` can return this already at least once used cell, and does not have to create a new instance (instantiating new cell is performance-wise less efficient).

Very simple - the only thing you have to realize is that while the `tableView` is retained, it will keep retained the cells that were dequeued as reusable cells. So when some reusable cell goes off the screen, it does NOT get released but still exists in memory, and the `tableView` keeps it in a queue so that it can be returned next time you call `dequeueReusableCell`.

Now if you realize this, you should also realize that if you don't clean up your resources after going off the screen, then you can get some ugly issues later - e.g., calling an asynchronous large image download on a cell can finish only after the cell was reused - and the old image will get presented on the cell where a new one should have been presented. All because you did not cancel the download in `prepareForReuse`.

Comment: As you mentioned in the 2nd type the previous cells are gone off the screen and waiting in the queue (last rows) ,when you are scrolling up and down.as per FIFO which cells are come and show?

Comment: Apple developer manual said ". A table view maintains a queue or list of UITableViewCell objects that the data source has marked for reuse." we are not sure Table view maintain the objects in queue or List.How we can find out ?

Comment: @appsign why is that important to you? I believe that is on purpose, it's an implementation detail that is hidden from you and it should stay hidden from you. your implementation should not rely on that, because they can change it in next release and your code would get broken

Comment: ,In IOS technical interviews all of them asking about dequeueReusableCell,But no one have clear idea about it.So I want to get more clarification on this topic,some of my friends lost their good opportunity due to this topic.So need all your help to understand

Comment: @appsign well, I don't know who was asking such a question, but in my opinion it is a stupid question that goes against the basic OOP principles.. implementation details should stay hidden from the users of the library (in this case of `dequeueReusableCell` method), so that underlying implementation would be flexible to change.. that's why documentation says nothing about how it is implemented on the inside - if they said it in documentaiton, they would have to keep that since it would become part of the contract..

Comment: @appsign moreover, the exact order in which the cells come back from that method is of no concern to the user.. why would you want to know? I cannot imagine a good use case in which that would be good thing to know

Answer (score 0):

You will get a number of cells as equal as the the height of visible portion of the table say cell height is 100 and tableView height is 500 , you will get 5 cells , as you scroll the new one that appears in the bottom dequeues the hidden one on the top

Comment: Nitpick - given your example, there will be 6 cells because at least part of 6 cells could be visible at one time.

Comment: I agree , as half of top will be shown it will be 6 , but first load will be 5 , also the number won't increase more than this

Comment: Even though if we didn't mentioned the height of cell and row we can see the cells in the table view.So confusing really any dequeue happening.

Comment: a cell will be dequeued if it's 1/10000000 of a pixel out of screen , if there isn't available one , then dequeue will create a new cell as happens when first load of the table

Answer (score 0):

Think cells as china plates and your content as food. So in your restaurant you only can show 20 plates maximum at a given time. But you have 100 types of food that you need to show them all depending on time. So for you to do that you do not need 100 china plates, you only need 20 and when you wanna show new food what you do is you remove the old one and put a new food on the same plate.

Cells are dequeued in the same manner. Just like plates you don't need 100 cell when you only have to show 20 at given time. You can put different content on the same cell. If you had 100 plates it is more expensive, more heavy just like if you have 100 cells it takes lots of memory and its heavy.

[image]

If you can see the picture here,

- Food 1 - food 20 is your data source.
- Plates are the same in both cases which are your cells.
- Location is the row number which is just counter

And this is the basic way it happens. The actual tableview works tiny bit different to keep some threshold values.

If you want to know how the cell reuse work there are better explanations online. You can check these links if you like.

[Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

[Good read](https://medium.com/ios-seminar/why-we-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-ce7fd97cde8e)

Comment: As you said to show 100 food in the table view we are not assigning rows 20.We assigned rows 100 for tableview right?.This what make me to ask this question to all.

Comment: No content does not have anything to do with your rows. You rows are related to your cells. when you scroll, rows are the numbers given to your cells placeholder. Think row number like your food name. 100 is your dataSource. May be the array you keep your data. Your cells are just 20. What you do is take a cell remove old food, and put new food from your datasource.